# Extension Method Listed for Non Supported Type. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I've created two extension methods: `FilterAnyType` that operates on `IEnumerable<T>`, and `FilterMovieType` that operates on `IEnumerable<Movie>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FilterAnyType<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,bool> predicate)
{
     //code goes here
}

public static IEnumerable<Movie> FilterMovieType<Movie>(this IEnumerable<Movie> source, Func<Movie, bool> predicate)
{
     //code goes here
}
```

And then, I've created two different lists:

```
var movies = new List<Movie>();
var customers = new List<Customer>();
```

As expected, the `FilterAnyType` method is available for both instances of `movie` and `customers`. However, the method `FilterMovieType` is also available to the `customer` instance, and I was not expecting that.

I am learning extension methods (hence this practice), and the way I understand it is that the `this` keyword is used to identify the type of object for which the extended method will be "added" to.

Given that, I'd expect that `FilterMovieType` would be available only to instances of `IEnumerable<Movie>`. Why is it also available to `IEnumerable<Customer>`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second method is still a generic, only you named your param `Movie`, not `T`. The Movie defined on `FilterMovieType` has no relation to actual Movie class, it is just a placeholder.
To fix it, remove `<Movie>` after method name, that is:

```
public static IEnumerable<Movie> FilterMovieType(this IEnumerable<Movie> source, Func<Movie, bool> predicate)
{
     //code goes here
}
```